# Parsley validation: after a successful input validation an empty element is remained in DOM

Tags: validation, parsley.js, parsley

I'm using parsley (parsleyjs.org) validation but after a field got validated, an empty element remains in the DOM. How can I remove it?

**It seems to be a Parsley bug: Parsley should remove the error container if there are no errors anymore.**

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyjmw.png)

Thank you.
Lui

Answer (score 0):

`parsley` chooses to keep that `<div>` around by design, but you can rely on it's class `filled` being present or not in your CSS. In short, your CSS rules that use `.parsley-errors-list` should read as `.parsley-errors-list.filled`.

Comment: It does not work for me, I've used in CSS the .filled class but the empty div remains there.

Comment: I would need a jquery script which will remove the .parsley-errors-list when the input is succeeded. It seems otherwise it is remined there.

Answer (score 0):

Only CSS was not working for me. This script does what I wanted. Removes the empty `.parsley-errors-list` elements.

```
$('#contactForm').parsley().on('field:success', function() { 
    $('ul.parsley-errors-list').not(':has(li)').remove();
});
```